# SugarCRM CE 6.5.11 Detail Views Broken

Tags: sugarcrm, suitecrm

We are working with SugarCRM CE 6.5.11. We created come custom fields within the Contacts and Accounts modules and imported some data. Now we can't access the Detail View of any of those modules.

We can create, for example, a new Lead and after creation the Detail View appears as usual.

However, once we go back to the Leads List View and click on a new Lead to see the detail view, we get nothing. We can only see the top menu and the SugarCRM footer. In Internet Explorer, it shows "null."

[image: Detailed view null]

This happens for any Detail View within Accounts, Leads and Contacts. We can create new ones and see the list, but there's no way to access the detail view. We also tried doing a quick fix from the repair menu with no luck.

Any ideas what can be broken?

Comment: Have you extended detail view generically or added a global logic hook, after retrieve?

Comment: Not that I know, Is there any way to check this? I wouldn't mind reseting to default. How can I do it? Thanks!

Comment: Check if you have a file under custom/modules/logic_hooks.php, if yes, paste the content here. For checking extended detail view, you should check if you have any file under custom/include/DetailView folder.

Comment: Edit config.php and set logger level to `debug` i.e. ( `'logger' => array ('level' => 'debug',`). Take detail view and check the end of sugarcrm.log file and see if you can find any relevant messages.